# Regular expression to remove first part of string leading to keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

I feel like I'm about to have a palm-to-the-forehead moment, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a path that I want to remove the beginning of it up to a certain folder(it's different folders, but the name of the folder will always be the same).

So, for **/path/to/templates/sometemplate.html** , I want the string to be just **templates/sometemplate.html**.(removed '/path/to/').  I can't just split on '/' and remove the first two, since another path could be **/yet/another/path/to/templates/sometemplate.html**  ....

Btw, I'm doing this in a Grunt script, so I'm looking at Javascript string.replace().

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: so what's that name of the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need regex here, just use `String` methods:

```
var s = '/yet/another/path/to/templates/sometemplate.html';
var r = s.substr(s.indexOf('/templates/') + 1)
//=> templates/sometemplate.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?(?=templates)
```

try this.replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/81